# How to flush entityManager's state after jdbcTemplate update

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity, which updated & created via `jdbcTemplate`:

```
transactionTemplate.execute {
    myRepository.save(MyEntity(...))
    jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE my_entity ...")
    entityManager.flush()
}

myRepository.getById(...) // Old version of entity from hibernate cache
```

But when I fetching updated entity, then I'm getting non-flushed version from cache. What is the problem here? For example, when I'm invoke native query with `Modifying`, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`flush()` writes changes from the `EntityManager` to the database. Therefore you most likely want to call it before doing updates not using JPA, like with the `JdbcTemplate`.

`flush()` does not remove entities from the cache of the `EntityManager` which you seem to be interested in. This is done by [`EntityManager.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--) or by [`EntityManager.detach(Object entity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-) for a single entity